# Jar file for MapReduce new API Job.getInstance(Configuration, String)

Tags: java, hadoop

Have setup Hadoop 2.2 .Trying to remove the deprecated API

```
    Job job = new Job(conf, "word count");
```

from example Wordcount (which comes with Hadoop ) [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-examples/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/examples/WordCount.java)

Replaced the deprecated API with

EDIT:

```
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
```

compile error is

> Job.getInstance cannot be resolved to a type.

The Job class which is already imported(old API or MR1) seems doesn't have this method.

Which jar contains this new Job class with `Job.getInstance(Configuratio,String)` method

How to resolve this? Are there any additional changes to the example to migrate to MapReduce v2?

Answer (score 4):

How I solved this issue was by adding [hadoop-core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core) as dependency. I had specified only [hadoop-common](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Job.getInstance cannot be resolved to a type.

You get the error message because, **required libraries are not present on your application class-path.** You need `hadoop-core*.jar` file present on your class-path to resolve this issue.

> By the way which jar contains this new Job class with
>   Job.getInstance(Configuratio,String) method

The `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job` class contained within `hadoop-core-*.jar` file. The jar file name will be appended by the hadoop version and vendor name (cdh - Cloudera, hdf - hortenworks etc.)

Suggestion:

`Job.getInstance()` is a static API, and you need not create an instance of the Job class to access it. Interestingly, `getInstance()` is used to create a new instance of the Job class, and if you already have one created using `new` keyword, you are not required to call `getInstance` again.

Replace `Job job = new Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");` with 
`Job job =  Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");`

Answer (score 1):

Change it with this

```
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf);
```

or

```
        Job job = new Job(new Configuration());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the old MapReduce API, continue using `new Job()` to create the instance. If you have migrated to the new API, use `Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");`

Answer (score 0):

Try that
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
change to
Job job = new Job(conf);

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using the wrong import statement for the Job class.

Make sure you are using `import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;`

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my experience.

My **pom.xml** it looks like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>apache</id>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Program code (**public static void main(String[] args)**):

```
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(YOUR_CLASS_NAME.class);
        job.setJobName("Word count");
```

Import instruction: `import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;`

I hope my answer will be useful. I wish you success!